# QBSDK 12 w/ QB Enterprise 13 - QBFC new custom menu items never appear

Tags: menu, quickbooks, qbfc

QBSDK 12 w/ QB Enterprise 13 - QBFC new custom menu items never appear

When I register and subscribe a QBFC application, I can get queries and data event handlers to work properly, but custom menu items never appear in QuickBooks Enterprise 13.0.  Any ideas?

What I have tried:

Using the sample application named "SubscribeAndHandleQBEvent" that can be downloaded from the samples section of the Intuit website, and the identical one that comes with QBSDK 12, I have followed the instructions to the letter: successfully registered, subscribed, restarted, etc etc and have the event that is called when a customer is added popping up properly with no problems, but the new custom menu items never appear.  Supposedly they should show up under the "customer" menu, and I've checked all menus, with no success.  When the admin permission screen for the app popped up, I gave it full permissions at all times, even if the company file is closed. I made zero changes to the code.

I also created a new "Intuit QBFC Application in C#" from the Visual Stuido menu, went through the Wizard and followed the instructions in the included documentation for their little sample program:  namely to add the simple listbox & button that will retrieve a list of customers.  (This works great.)  I also added the code for the menu event handler and the data event handler, with a simple copy/paste.  No other customizations were made.  As before, I followed the instructions to the letter, registered the program using administrator credentialed command prompt, subscribed using user-credentialed command prompt with success.  The data event handler works perfectly, popping up a message box when a new customer is created.  Again, the custom menu items do not appear on the menus.

In both situations, I did not add any modifiers to the "Visible" or "Enabled" settings, which should be always enabled and always visible by default, as per the documentation.

I tried every combination of restarting QuickBooks, subscribing, registering, etc. that I could think of, with identical results every time:  all facets of the communication work, but the menu items never appear.

I have thoroughly read the section of the QBSDK Programming Guide ver 11.0 that pertains to adding custom menu items, with nothing confusing, unusual, or helpful found.  It offers no trouble-shooting information if the menu items don't appear, and it sure seems like it should be simple.

I'm using:

Windows 8 Pro 64-Bit
QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions - Manufacturing and Wholesale 13.0
QBSDK12
Visual Studio 2012 w/ C#

Thanks for any advice you could offer!

P.S.  I checked event viewer to see if any application errors were thrown, and didn't see anything.

Comment: Hi Jeremy i'm facing same problem That Menu not added under file menu but when i check in Preferences it shows.. If you get solution please help me .....

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the most common cause of this problem is that you need to run quickbooks as a windows administrator and login as a quickbooks administrator before the new menu options will appear.  The running as a windows administrator part is the one that most often trips folks up, because your app will function properly (receive company file open events, etc.) but the menu options just own't appear.

Comment: Hi Simmdan, in my side it is working for 2010,2012 .But it doesn't added in 2013 with Windows8(OS). i tried many time run the setup as RunAsAdmin many times even-though it is not working .... is there any other way ...

Answer (score 0):

"Something the documentation doesn't cover (cause it is older than UAC) Is after your Request to modify the menu is you have to run QuickBooks as administrator. Once it is modified you don't need to run it elevated anymore."

[link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489215/add-menu-item-to-quickbooks)

I saw this on other post, and it works!!!,

1.-be sure quickbooks process isnt running.

2.-register the events from the samplev"SubscribeAndHandleQBEvent"

3.-Run quickbooks with admin Rights and log in as administrator

you should see the menu now.